# delaying enemy attacks

Tags: unity, c#

I have an enemy attack script that when a raycast hits the player it deals damage to the player, however the enemy attacks at multiple times per second and I wish for the enemy to have to wait 1 second after it attacks the player before it can attack again. The script is here, the main focal point is the `void update()`. Any help is appreciated, let me know if I've missed out any needed details. :)

```
public class DamagePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    int attackDamage = 10;
    

    [SerializeField]
    float agroRange;

    [SerializeField]
    Transform castPoint;

    

    Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    bool isFacingLeft;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    bool CanSeePlayer(float distance)
    {
        bool val = false;
        float castDist = distance;

        if (isFacingLeft == true)
        {
            castDist = -distance;
        }

        Vector2 endPos = castPoint.position + Vector3.right * castDist;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(castPoint.position, endPos, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Action"));

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                val = true;

            }
            else
            {
                val = false;
            }

            Debug.DrawLine(castPoint.position, endPos, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(castPoint.position, endPos, Color.green);
        }

        return val;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (CanSeePlayer(agroRange))
        {
            PlayerHealth.currentHealth -= attackDamage;
            //Debug.Log("can see player");
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt in this code to introduce an attack cooldown, such as via a timer variable or a coroutine with a wait. What did you try doing to solve this problem, based on all the research you did and tutorials you worked through or past Q&A you read up on before posting here?

Comment: I am pretty sure I answered this question several times on this website, but I still can't find any fitting answer via search function right now. So here, have a new version of it.

Comment: Here is a super helpful link on a bunch of ways to wait in unity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-to-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a private variable to the script which represents the remaining cooldown time for the enemy attack.
2. Reduce that time in each `Update()` by `Time.deltaTime`
3. Only allow the enemy to attack when the cooldown is lower or equal than `0f`
4. When the enemy attacks, restore the value of that variable to the desired cooldown duration in seconds.

Example script:

```
public class DamagePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
      public float attackCooldown; // Seconds between attacks
      private float attackCooldownLeft; // Seconds left until this object can attack again
      
      void Update() {
          attackCooldownLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
          if (attackCooldownLeft <= 0f && CanAttackPlayer()) {
               attackCooldownLeft = attackCooldown;
               DamagePlayer();
          }
      }

      private void CanAttackPlayer() {
         // Game-specific logic to determine if the mob should attack the player right now
      }

      private void AttackPlayer() {
         // Game-specific logic for performing one (1) attack on the player
      }
}
```

When your game has very high attack frequencies, then there might be occasions where the attack frequency is supposed to be higher than the current update frequency the user's device is capable of maintaining. In that case you should use the following code instead which allows multiple attacks in a single update. But note that it will enter an infinite loop if `attackCooldown` ever becomes 0 or negative for any reason (like you forgetting to set a value in the inspector), which means the game/editor will hang and needs to be killed via task manager, losing any progress since last time player/you saved the game/project:

```
      void Update() {
          attackCooldownLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
          while (attackCooldownLeft <= 0f && CanAttackPlayer()) {
               attackCooldownLeft += attackCooldown;
               AttackPlayer();
          }
      }
```